# How to get the device locale after changing the application locale

Tags: android, location, locale, device

I am changing the application locale based on user choice. Independent of device locale.

using

```
public void setDefaultLocale(Context context, String locale) {
        Locale appLoc = new Locale(locale);
        Locale.setDefault(appLoc);
        Configuration appConfig = new Configuration();
        appConfig.locale = appLoc;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(appConfig,
                context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

But I want to know what will be the device locale also.

When I am trying to get this I always getting the locale which I have set to application.

ex: applictaion is in ***ENGLISH*** and device is in ***CHINESE***.
I am always getting ***english***.

for getting locale using,

**option 1.**

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

**option 2.**

```
String local_country = ((Activity) context).getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348954/android-get-device-locale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am absolutely unsure how portable this is to different devices:

```
try {
    Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"getprop", "persist.sys.language"});
    String locale = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream())).readLine();
    exec.destroy();
    Log.e("", "Device locale: "+locale);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And if you want the country part: persist.sys.country

Comment: On Android Api(+21) instead of using persist.sys.language use persist.sys.locale

Answer (score 7):

I asked something similar and found this answer, sorry if it is late:

To find the system locale use:

```
defaultLocale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
```

It gets the system locale, no matter which default locale is set for the app/activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support below Android 7.0 - Nougat (API level 24) you can use something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
// ToDo: Adjust this method once the target API is 24 or higher!
private Locale getLocale()
{
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
  {
    return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
  }

  else
  {
    return Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
  }
}
```

Note the annotation regarding `deprecation` and `NewApi`. Adjust this method once you target API 24 or higher. Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23538518) answer.

Answer (score 0):

for those whom are using `Daniel Fekete` 's solution which is :

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"getprop", "persist.sys.language"});
String locale = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream())).readLine();
exec.destroy();
```

Be aware of that locale might be **EMPTY** on latest Android Api(+21)! instead of using `persist.sys.language` use **persist.sys.locale**

```
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"getprop", "persist.sys.locale"});
locale = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream())).readLine();
exec.destroy();
```